# Why can't I apply ModularityState from graph-tool on a graph in XML format?

Tags: graph, graph-theory, modularity, graph-tool

I keep getting this error:

RuntimeError: boost::bad_any_cast: failed conversion using boost::any_cast

g = gt.load_graph("graph.xml")
state = gt.minimize_blockmodel_dl(g, state=gt.ModularityState)

or modularity_state = ModularityState(g)